# iPhone states it has IP address A. Access point says iPhone has IP address B. What gives?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iphone, pfsense

I have an iphone, a unifi AP and a pfsense router. I set pfsense to give out static IP addresses. My iPhone is supposed to receive 10.12.1.144.

Well according to my iPhone, the Ip address it recieved is 10.12.1.28. When I go onto my AP's web gui and looked at the connected clients, it reports that my iPhone is connected with 10.12.1.144.

Why is my iphone reporting a different IP address?

Comment: Are there multiple iPhones on your network? Do the MAC addresses match between the router and the phone?

Comment: *give out static IP addresses*...I think you mean give out **DHCP** addresses.

Comment: @Twisty, no, he said it right. DHCP is a protocol to give out IP addresses. It is often used to dynamically assign addresses that may differ from one connection to the next, but it can also be configured to give out the same unchanging (static) IP address to the same client each time. So it's a static IP address, just via DHCP instead of manual/local configuration.

Comment: @Spiff In my experience, the terms "static" and "dynamic" refer to *how* the address is assigned. To call a DHCP reservation a static address creates confusion between that assignment method and that of manually configuring an address on the host. If a static address is simply an address that doesn't change, then *all* addresses would be static for as long as their DHCP lease was valid.

Comment: @Spiff However to your point, you correctly observed the OP is using a DHCP reservation, whereas I thought he was referring to a standard DHCP lease.

Comment: Was this question closed because it mentions an iPhone? IMO, the iPhone could be a laptop and the question would be the same.

Comment: … and the question ***is*** about how the device interfaces with a computer network, which is the explicitly stated exception to the “no phones” rule.

Comment: @Twisty It's a common misconception. But in English, "dynamic vs. static" means "changing vs. unchanging". Also, DHCP was built atop BootP, a much older protocol that always used static IP addresses even though they were assigned from the BootP server. So the idea that static IP addresses can be remotely configured at boot time predates DHCP and DHCP reservations.

Comment: @Spiff When I configure a DHCP reservation in a DNS server, it's called a *DHCP reservation*, not a static IP address assignment. Certainly you wouldn't call a manually assigned IP address on a node "dynamic" just because I manually change it every 8 hours.

Comment: @OP: When did you add the DHCP reservation? Right before checking the phone's address? Did you try disabling/enabling wifi on the phone or even rebooting it? Where on your phone did it indicate the wrong IP address?

Comment: Have you disconnected from the WiFi and reconnected to it after making the static address reservation? If you connected to the WiFi and then made the reservation, it won't automatically reassign you the new address.

Answer (score 0):

Because your router always assigns a different IP to your different devices and all of them are in sequential form, so the ip that your router communicates with the internet is different and the ip asssigned by your router to different device devices connected varies.